# Android studio gridlayout overflow screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

My GridLayout overflows the screen even though I used match_parent for each card. I have also tried to specify the height and width for each card and it appears perfectly on my laptop. However, once I open the apk on my phone, it overflows too. Can someone please help me with that?

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> ```
> \<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>     android:background="@color/beige"
>
>     tools:context=".MainActivity"\>
>
>
>
>     \<TextView
>
>         android:id="@+id/titleHome"
>
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>         android:text="Senior Tech"
>
>         android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
>
>         android:textSize="40sp"
>
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
>         android:layout_margin="12dp"/\>
>
>
>
>     \<GridLayout
>
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>         android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
>
>         android:layout_below="@+id/titleHome"
>
>         android:layout_margin="20sp"
>
>         android:columnCount="2"
>
>         android:rowCount="3"\>
>
>
>
>         \<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>
>             android:id="@+id/cardTouchNGo"
>
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>             android:layout_row="0"
>
>             android:layout_column="0"
>
>             android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>
>             android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>
>             android:layout_gravity="fill"
>
>             app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/lightgreen"
>
>             app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>
>             app:cardElevation="8dp"
>
>             app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>
>             \>
>
>
>
>             \<LinearLayout
>
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
>
>                 android:gravity="center"
>
>                 android:orientation="vertical"\>
>
>
>
>                 \<ImageView
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:src="@drawable/img" /\>
>
>
>
>                 \<TextView
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:text="Touch N Go"
>
>                     android:textAlignment="center"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
>
>                     android:textSize="20dp"
>
>                     android:textStyle="bold" /\>
>
>
>
>             \</LinearLayout\>
>
>
>
>         \</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView\>
>
>
>
>         \<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>
>             android:id="@+id/cardMAE"
>
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>             android:layout_row="0"
>
>             android:layout_column="1"
>
>             android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>
>             android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>
>             android:layout_gravity="fill"
>
>             app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/lightgreen"
>
>             app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>
>             app:cardElevation="8dp"
>
>             app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>
>             \>
>
>
>
>             \<LinearLayout
>
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
>
>                 android:gravity="center"
>
>                 android:orientation="vertical"\>
>
>
>
>                 \<ImageView
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:src="@drawable/maeicon" /\>
>
>
>
>                 \<TextView
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:text="MAE"
>
>                     android:textAlignment="center"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
>
>                     android:textSize="20dp"
>
>                     android:textStyle="bold" /\>
>
>
>
>             \</LinearLayout\>
>
>
>
>         \</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView\>
>
>
>
>     \</GridLayout\>
>
>
>
> \</RelativeLayout\>
> ```

My phone doesn't show all the cards, only half of it were shown.

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="Senior Tech"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleHome"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardTouchNGo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Touch N Go"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardMAE"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MAE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this

Comment: It can be more specific if we can also identify and explain the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).